# How can I install an additional version of a compiler-specific library with CMake when another version has already been installed?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, netcdf

*I will use NetCDF Fortran to outline this example however, this problem can be encountered with other libraries.*

**Prior Assumptions:**

- OS: `Ubuntu Trusty (14.04LTS)`
- NetCDF-4 version already present: `libnetcdf-dev (1:4.1.3-7ubuntu2)` (see: [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libnetcdf-dev/filelist))
- Additional NetCDF-4 fortran to be added to the system: `netcdf-fortran 4.4.3` (get it from [here](ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-fortran-4.4.3.tar.gz))
- Build Method: `CMake v3+`
- Script used to insall additional `netcdf-fortran`:

  ```
      wget ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-fortran-4.4.3.tar.gz
      tar xvzf netcdf-fortran-4.4.3.tar.gz
      cd netcdf-fortran-4.4.3
      mkdir build && cd build
      cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/netcdf-fortran-ifort -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF ..
      cmake --build . --target install
      rm -rf *
  ```

My questions are 2:

1. How can I buid and install `netcdf-fortran` using the Intel fortran compiler (`ifort`)  assuming that a version of `netcdf-fortran` has already been installed under the the default system library path (`/usr`) (NB: a version of `netcdf-c` and `netcdf-fortran` has already been installed via `apt-get` (see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libnetcdf-dev/filelist) for installation path by apt-get))?

My current problem is that CMake includes the path `/usr/include` before any other paths. The build fails because `.mod` files are found in the `include` directory which belong to the previous installation of NetCDF-4 (i.e. the one obtained via `apt-get`, compiled with `gcc`).
A quick solution (which works) is to temporarily 'park' or rename the `.mod` files so that they would not be found during the build process, however this does not appear to me to be a particular good solution.
How can I move `/usr/include` to the end of the `INCLUDE_PATH` at configure time so that the `.mod` files generated with `ifort` will be used instead? Or can anyone suggest a better solution?

2. How can I 'make' the system select the appropriate `netcdf-fortran` library and dependencies when compiling a program with a specific compiler - e.g. the `netcdf-fortran` compiled with `ifort` above - when compiling a program that requires a version of `netcdf-fortran` compiled with `ifort` or `netcdf-fortran` compiled with `gcc`?

I am using [this](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/CMake/FindNetCDF.cmake) CMake script to find the NetCDF library installed on the system. My issue is to find a way to 'tell' CMake to 'pick' the correct `netcdf-fortran` when I require my program to be compiled with `ifort` istead of `gcc`.